# Duas tabelas retornando um só resultado

Tags: sql, firebird

```
select
        cliente.codcliente,
        cliente.dt_cadastro
from cliente
where cliente.codcliente in ('00000224', '00000170', '00061825', '01009838')
order by cliente.codcliente
```

[image: Resultado 1]

```
select  nfsaidc.codcliente,
        nfsaidc.numnf,
        nfsaidc.dt_emissao,
        nfsaidc.totalnf
from nfsaidc
where NFSAIDC.CODCLIENTE in ('00000224', '00000170', '00061825', '01009838') 
order by nfsaidc.numnf
```

[image: Resultado 2]

Pessoal, preciso retonar somente uma linha de cada cliente com as colunas CODCLIENTE, DT_CADASTRO, NUMNF, DT_EMISSAO, TOTALNF. O resultado seria a data que o cliente foi cadastro com a primeira compra realizada.
O resultado que preciso seria o da imagem abaixo:
[image: Resultado esperado]

Estou utilizando o IBEXPERT com o Firebird 2.1 mas aceito sugestoes de outras plataformas.

Comment: Tem que eliminar os zeros a esquerda também ?

Comment: Não precisa!! A formatacao que foi errada

Comment: Charles, seu problema foi resolvido? Teria algo a mais que posso explicar?

Answer (score 1):

Charles, não tenho como simular aqui, mas o conceito (SQL) é esse:

```
SELECT CL.codcliente, CL.dt_cadastro, NF.numnf, MIN(NF.dt_emissao), NF.totalnf
FROM nfsaidc NF
LEFT OUTER JOIN cliente CL ON CL.codcliente = NF.codcliente
GROUP BY CL.codcliente
ORDER BY CL.codcliente
```

Comment: Dependendo da engine de sql, dará erro de código, pois você está agrupando apenas por uma coluna e retornando diversas

Comment: Exato, aí pode tentar usar o `DISTINCT`. Não devo ter usado firebird nem 5x na vida ! rs